# Word regarding a lyric remembered wrongly

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember having come across a particular word long ago. This word means a part of lyric that has been remembered wrongly, i.e., a section of lyric that has entered one's memory with the words mangled up in some way (Spoonerism, for example). The word remembered could be differing from the original word in a facetious way.

Does anyone know of this word?

Comment: I can certainly think of occasions where the artist quite simply *did not* sing the official lyric. Not to mention occasions where the official lyric is clearly less poetic than what I hear. :)

Comment: Gimme fried chicken!

Comment: This issue has actually [come up before on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21241/), and **mondegreen** was given in the top answer. But that other one was closed because it didn't quite ask the question the right way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called a *[mondegreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)*, such as *[scuse me while I kiss this guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_Haze)* or *[there's a bathroom on the right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Moon_Rising_)*:

> [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) A mondegreen is the mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as
> a result of near homophony, in a way that gives it a new meaning. It
> most commonly is applied to a line in a poem or a lyric in a song.
> American writer Sylvia Wright coined the term in her essay "The Death
> of Lady Mondegreen," published in Harper's Magazine in November 1954.

[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_Haze) [Jimi Hendrix, *Purple Haze*]
A common misheard lyric in the song is "excuse me while I kiss this guy". The actual line is "excuse me while I kiss the sky". In fact, it has even been documented that Jimi Hendrix himself perpetrated this mondegreen by actually using it as a joke while singing "Purple Haze" live in concert, particularly at the Monterey Pop Festival in 1967. In Cheech & Chong's film *Nice Dreams*, the line is parodied as "excuse me while I kiss this fly".

[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Moon_Rising_)  [Creedence Clearwater Revival, *Bad Moon Rising*] The refrain in the chorus, "there's a bad moon on the rise", is commonly misheard as "there's a bathroom on the right". Fogerty has parodied the mishearing in live performances of the song.

Comment: Pop culture refers to these as "misheard lyrics."  Cool to learn there's a more proper name for them.  I'm going to have to share this word with my friend, [Reverend Bluejeans](http://www.kissthisguy.com/813song-Forever-In-Blue-Jeans.htm).

Comment: Awesome @cornbread ninja! You have got it almost instantaneously I believe. Thanks.